# Unable to do the app registrations on Azure Cloud

Tags: azure, devops, grafana, azure-log-analytics

I'm pretty new to the whole devops world, the Azure account heirachy is something that always boggles me. I have two questions in here.

1. How different are the various levels in Azure accounts (Owner/Tenant)
2. I have a tenant account and even though I have owner level permissions on my subscription, I'm unable to perform an app registration nor create a service principal. I'm trying to connect my Azure monitor to Grafana to be able to visualize logs better, but his is now stalling the development. I'm also unable to view the Access Control dashboard to get a better idea of my roles.

Answer (score 0):

An Azure Active Directory tenant exists above the subscriptions and that is where app registrations and service principals live.
Your rights in subscriptions/resource groups only mean something to the Azure Resource Management API; they mean nothing to Azure AD.

In order to create app registrations in the Azure AD tenant, you would need something like the *Application Developer* directory role assigned to your user in the Azure AD tenant.
Not sure if that is enough in this particular scenario.